# Visualize long division with ASCII art

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, arithmetic, division

Write a program that visualizes long division with ASCII art.  Input consists of two integers, a numerator and a denominator, using the input format of your choice.

**Examples:**

1234 ÷ 56:

```
     22
   ----
56|1234
   112
   ---
    114
    112
    ---
      2
```

1002012 ÷ 12:

```
     83501
   -------
12|1002012
    96
   ---
     42
     36
     --
      60
      60
      --
        12
        12
        --
```

0 ÷ 35

```
   0
   -
35|0
```

**Rules:**

- Use of the programming language's division operator **is** allowed.
- Use of big integer support is also allowed.
- For consistency:

  - If the quotient is zero, print a single zero at the end of the diving board.
  - If the remainder is zero, do not print it.
  - Do not print leading zeros on any numbers.
- Excess newlines at the end and trailing spaces to the right are allowed.
- Solution with the fewest characters wins.

**Limits:**

- 0 <= numerator <= 10<sup>72</sup> - 1
- 1 <= denominator <= 9999999

This implies that the output will never be wider than 80 columns.

**Test suite and sample implementation:**

You can use [long-division.c](https://gist.github.com/raw/869887/long-division.c) ([gist](https://gist.github.com/869887)) to test your program.  It is actually a bash script with a C program inside.  Tweak it to invoke your program in the test suite.  Look at the C code at the bottom to see the reference implementation.  Please let me know if there are any problems with the sample program or test suite.

```
$ ./long-division.c 10 7
   1
  --
7|10
   7
  --
   3
$ ./long-division.c
PASS 1234 ÷ 56
PASS 1002012 ÷ 12
PASS 1 ÷ 1
--- snip ---

Score: 35 / 35
All tests passed!
```

**Edit:** By request, I put the test suite [input](https://gist.github.com/raw/870827/input) and [expected output](https://gist.github.com/raw/870827/expected) into text files ([gist](https://gist.github.com/870827)).  Sample usage (bash):

```
cat input | while read nd; do
    ./program $nd |
        sed 's/\s*$//' | sed -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;};/\n$/ba'
done > output

diff -u expected output
```

The weird sed commands filter out trailing newlines and spaces from the program output.

Comment: I think the output is a bit biased towards the English-speaking golfing audience: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division#Notation_in_non-English-speaking_parts_of_the_world

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Python 3, <s>284</s> 257 characters

### div.py

```
n,t=input().split()
d=int(t)
l=lambda x:len(str(x))
s=l(n)
def p(x):print(' '*(l(d)+s-l(x)+1)+str(x))
p(int(n)//d)
p('-'*s)
p(t+'|'+n)
s=z=f=0
while t:
 try:
  while z<d:z=z*10+int(n[s]);s+=1
 except:t=0
 if z*f:p(z)
 if t:f=1;t=z//d*d;p(t);p('-'*l(z));z-=t
```

Usage: `python3 div.py`
Input: from keyboard

### test.py

```
import sys
sys.stdin=open('input'); sys.stdout=open('output','w')
for line in open('input'): exec(open('div.py').read())
```

*output* matches *expected*

Versions:
 1. [284](http://ideone.com/90gcH)
 2. [257](http://ideone.com/r99o6): `s,z,f=0,0,0`→`s=z=f=0`; `z and f`→`z*f`; better looping; removed a few newlines.

Comment: you may try ideone for python3 and input - http://ideone.com/clone/ZZyzu

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 320 characters

```
l=length
(®)=replicate
p!v=p&show v
p&s=(p-l s)®' '++s
0§_=[];_§l=l
d[m,n]=l c!(read m`div`e):l c&(l m®'-'):c:drop 1(g 0(map(toInteger.fromEnum)m)$1+l n)where
 e=read n;c=n++'|':m
 g r(d:z)p=i§[o!k,o!(i*e),o&(l(show k)®'-')]++g j z o where k=r*10+d-48;(i,j)=k`divMod`e;o=1+p
 g r[]p=r§[p!r]
main=interact$unlines.d.words
```

Passes all tests. While is this pretty golf'd -- I think there is still yet more to be done here...

---

- Edit: (344 -> 339) delay `read` calls, which reduces need to call `show`, enough that abbreviating `show` as `s` isn't worth it.
- Edit: (339 -> 320) rewrote string field formatting functions

Comment: Neat!  I did a Haskell solution with 344 characters, but didn't post it.  Also, I didn't know you could use Unicode symbols for operators (without `-XUnicodeSyntax`).

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (400 <strike>394</strike> <strike>418</strike>)

```
function d(n,d){t=parseInt;p=function(v){return(s+v).substring(v.length)};a=function(v,c){return v.replace(/\d/g,c)};w='\n';q=b=o=c=e='';s=a(d,' ')+' ';f=true;i=-1;z='0';while(++i<n.length){s+=' ';if(t(c+=n[i])>=t(d)){q+=r=Math.floor(t(c)/t(d));o+=(!f?p(c)+w:e)+p(''+r*t(d))+w+p(a(c,'-'))+w;c=t(c)%t(d);f=false}else if(!f){q+=z;}c=(c==0)?e:e+c}return p(!q?z:q)+w+p(a(n,'-'))+w+d+'|'+n+w+o+(q?p(c):e)}
```

NOTE: As tempting as it looks to shave off a few chars by replacing `c=(c==0)?` with `c=!c?`, it is not usable because it causes floating point-related bugs.

[http://jsfiddle.net/nLzYW/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/nLzYW/5/)

Sample Execution:

```
document.writeln("<pre>");
document.writeln(d("1234","56"));
document.writeln();
document.writeln(d("1002012","12"));
document.writeln();
document.writeln(d("0","35"));
document.writeln();
document.writeln(d("123000123000123","123"));
document.writeln("</pre>");
```

**Edit 1**: Minor bug fixes, numerous code optimizations.

**Edit 2**: Fix bug with 1/7 generating extra output.

Comment: [314 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY3NTsMwEITvPEUViXhdJ6mTUA6YLU/AqUfKIdhOGmTZ@Wsq9efZg1tRDqiX1c7MfrPfxVj0squbIbZO6UnhBDZSUUlxdWxwxBWs2UiTfvfVD11tKxgTo201bKkoEMZI@sMx6XRjCqlhsVGLyntij2RjiWjRoUSNhIg1FqAig2RGKDOixjgVBySciNJ1cJWM1bH9rRceYyDnaRhKSo9rhp4pQb1iOgfJ0H7Un95vGXb4XgzbpDTO98iFosIxhPKtAUnZ/kVT1gAhrJsrL/1egIxITKhX/ol8VKLE9KxNr2dlGIJvPNBzp4ddZ2cNtKfT4cbZG8cUIyfCrN8cgzYML7/oeZLO9s7oxLgKFARplj8FUbB8DigVD/9DzjOeZj73407OfZIv75JZzjn/m9eG/HI4/QA)

Answer (score 3):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 422 bytes

I think it took me over a week to solve this problem.

```
function l(x){return length(x)}{P=9(d=$2);gsub(".",FS,P);N=l(L=n=$1);gsub(".","-",L);O(0,q=int($1/$2));Q=l(q);print P L RS d"|"n}function O(i,x){printf"%"l(d)+N-Q+1+i"d\n",x}m=substr(q,1,1)*d{for(i=1;i<=Q;){O(i,m);print P substr(L,1,N-Q+1);for(_=l(j=n)-l(n-=m*10**(Q-i));_--;)P=P FS;if(!n)exit;match(q,".0*");i+=R=RLENGTH;sub(".{"R"}",E,q);b=q+0?substr(n,1,M=l(m=substr(q,1,1)*d)):n;if(b<m)b=substr(n,1,M+1);O(i-(i>Q),b)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9dT8IwFIb/Sm0w6dk6XPETy9Er1IsJ2/DShDDGoLoVN0Ykmfvts0OiJN41p885z/vOPt@bJtnqeanWmqRsB1WxKLeFeS/0slyZQV352Gcxdnogl5ttxGiX8ocJ90GOMGUeauyIoy/qUO6BHDOX56h0yTrizOyCDAydg/wozJD4xCPhhMT0i@r6N8CYKW4i7JGEntKUxWCPnMAWtqLxq6Z8V2doTJuyYDkXXIAVV8m6YAqFVAMMJFTtkezPc6A9Q@8vgWz5qQnzhhqclGkHM0u4lsUCR5mcU8eR4KNPHiZSJexEw2KnSpnNyvnKSGnXtShIZWOIoTccPb48yZ/uFQ1pTfmQm5YR5rZ7f3Br4342wn/RAW5164gGGUR4TLc5TRGHqbsAeAR13TSEiN75xeUVub7pu98)

### Usage

- Input is given from STDIN, as single line.
- Two natural numbers are on same line.
- Output is returned to STDOUT.
- This program does never handle overflow; fails on huge values.
- This program does not handle multiple lines of input correctly; only the first line is handled correctly.

### Formatted

```
function l(x){
  return length(x)}
{
  P=9(d=$2);gsub(".",FS,P);
  N=l(L=n=$1);gsub(".","-",L);
  O(0,q=int($1/$2));
  Q=l(q);
  print P L RS d"|"n}
function O(i,x){
  printf"%"l(d)+N-Q+1+i"d\n",x}
m=substr(q,1,1)*d{
  for(i=1;i<=Q;){
    O(i,m);
    print P substr(L,1,N-Q+1);
    for(_=l(j=n)-l(n-=m*10**(Q-i));_--;)
      P=P FS;
    if(!n)
      exit;
    match(q,".0*");
    i+=R=RLENGTH;
    sub(".{"R"}",E,q);
    b=q+0?substr(n,1,M=l(m=substr(q,1,1)*d)):n;
    if(b<m)
      b=substr(n,1,M+1);
    O(i-(i>Q),b)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript: (372)

```
function g(a){for(var c="",e=0;e<a;e++)c=" "+c;return c}function i(a,c){for(var e=a+"/"+c+"\\",j=(""+c).split(""),k="",d=0,b=0;b<j.length;b++){d*=10;d+=parseInt(j[b],10);var f=d>9?b-1:b,h=0;h=Math.floor(d/a);d%=a;f=g(f+a.toString().split("").length);f+=h*a+"\n"+g(b+a.toString().split("").length)+"--\n"+g(b+a.toString().split("").length)+d+"\n";k+=f;e+=h}return e+"\n"+k}
```

Invoke by using i(divider,number).
Codegolfed JS: http://jsfiddle.net/puckipedia/EP464/
Ungolfed (dutch) JS: http://jsfiddle.net/puckipedia/M82VM/

Returns the long division (in dutch format as i learned it):

```
5/25\05
 0
 --
 2
 25
  --
  0
```

Testcase:

```
document.write("<pre>"+i(5,25)+"</pre>");
document.write("<pre>"+i(7,65669726752476)+"</pre>");
```

Comment: Interesting. Though as @BlaXpirit says, it doesn't follow the spec. The spec is intended to be a fair standard of comparison for determining efficiency of code-golfed code, so you can't arbitrarily change the spec even if you don't agree with the output format :)