# Visualise long multiplication with ASCII art

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, arithmetic

### The challenge

Write a program that takes two integers from standard input, separated by a comma, and then prints a visualisation of long multiplication of those two integers to standard output.

Eg:

**Input**

```
14, 11
```

**Program output**

```
     14
    x11
   _____
     14
    14
  ______
    154
```

**Input**

```
-7, 20
```

**Program output**

```
     -7
    x20
   _____
     00
    14
   _____
   -140
```

Assume always correct inputs and numbers in the range [-999, 999]

### Winning criteria

Shortest code wins!

Comment: Tweaked for consistency with http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/visualize-long-division-with-ascii-art

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Perl, 108 chars

Best of breed 108 char solution, incorporating some ideas from Orabig.

```
($x,$y)=<>=~/[-\d]+/g;printf"%7s
",$_ for$x,x.$y,"-"x7,(map{abs($x*$_).$"x$i++}reverse$y=~/\d/g),"-"x7,$x*$y
```

Earlier 139 char solution

```
sub P{sprintf"%*d",@_}
($x,$y)=<>=~/[^,]+/g;$,=$/;
print P(7,$x),"  x".P(4,$y),"-"x7,(map{P 7-$i++,abs$_*$x}reverse$y=~/\d/g),
"-"x7,P 7,$x*$y
```

Comment: /me bow in respect... I didn't see the possibility to include the map in the printf part. And the `$y=~/\d/g` trick was clever

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica <strike>213 217 197 193 186 184 193 184</strike> 177

**Code**

```
a_~g~b_ := 
With[{e = IntegerDigits@b}, Column[Flatten@{a, UnderBar["x " <> IntegerString[b]], 
Table[Row @@ {PadRight[{a Reverse[e][[i]]}, i, " "]}, {i, Length@e}], OverBar[a b]}, 
Alignment -> Right]]
```

**Usage**

```
g[845, 921]
```

[image: multiply]

Comment: Surely by `IntegerString[921]` you mean `IntegerString[b]`?

Comment: Yes, good catch!

Comment: I think the spec allows for the removal of the space in `"x "`.

Comment: Your're correct.  I decided to leave it in because it looked better (and I wasn't going to have the shortest code anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Python, <strike>174</strike> 170:

```
a,b=input();r,s=str(a),str(b);h=len(r+s)*'-';print'\n'.join(["%9s\n%9s\n%9s"%(r,'x'+s,h)]+["%%%ii"%(9-i)%(int(d)%10*a)for i,d in enumerate(s[::-1])]+["%9s\n%9i"%(h,a*b)])
```

Usage: exactly as requested, run and input the values in standard input.

To see running: http://ideone.com/S8xNb

Output:

```
     1234
    x5678
 --------
     9872
    8638
   7404
  6170
 --------
  7006652
```

Thanks to fabiocerqueira and beary605 and David Carraher

Comment: You can remove 4 characters of whitespace: `print '\n'` -> `print'\n'`, `10*a) for i,d in enumerate` -> `10*a)for i,d in enumerate`, `"%9s\n%9i" % (h,a*b)` -> `"%9s\n%9i"%(h,a*b)`

Answer (score 1):

Python, 145, another answer with a little bit different output.

**Code**

```
a,b=input();h=6*'-';print'\n'.join(["%6i\nx%5i\n%s"%(a,b,h)]+["%%%ii"%(6-i)%(int(d)%10*a)for i,d in enumerate(str(b)[::-1])]+["%s\n%6i"%(h,a*b)])
```

**Usage**

just as requested

**Output**

```
   999
x  999
------
  8991
 8991
8991
------
998001
```

To see running: http://ideone.com/mdR18

Answer (score 1):

**Perl**, <strike>157</strike> <strike>151</strike> <strike>150</strike> <strike>144</strike> <strike>141</strike> 133 chars :

```
($x,$y)=<>=~/[-\d]+/g;map{$z=~s/z/ z/g;$z=(abs$x*$_)."z$z"}split//,abs$y;map{printf"%6s
",$_}$x,"x$y",$b="-"x6,(split/z/,$z),$b,$x*$y
```

**Usage :**

```
>echo "-123, 456" | perl mult.pl
   -123
   x456
-------
    738
   615
  492
-------
 -56088
```

Comment: Had an idea this morning : using printf make me improve my solution by 8 characters :)