# Visualize long addition with ASCII art

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

<sub>Totally not inspired by [Visualize long division with ASCII art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/visualize-long-division-with-ascii-art) ;)</sub>

Your job is to show long hand addition with ASCII art. You solve longhand addition by adding up the columns right to left, placing the value of the ones place in the result, and carrying the tens place over to the top of the next column.

### Input

Input can come basically in any format you want, just as long as you take from 2 to 9 numbers as input.

### Output

The formatting here likely matches how you learned it in school:

```
carry row
 number1 
 number2
     ...
+   numX
--------
  result
```

You can have just about any amount of trailing whitespace you want here ;)

### Examples

```
50, 50

1
 50
+50
---
100


1651, 9879

1111
 1651
+9879
-----
11530

6489789, 9874, 287

   1122
 6489789
    9874
+    287
--------
 6499950
```

Comment: Visualize long subtraction with ASCII art: Coming straight to you in 6 months

Comment: Not quite, it's on my list ;)

Comment: Actually I was taught to put the carry row under the result.

Comment: How should we handle `9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9`?

Comment: @Downgoat ...`you take from 2 to 9 numbers as input`...

Comment: @Pietu1998 Yeah, I didn't want to figure out how to carry one hundred :\

Comment: To generalize to larger number of input values, we could place spaces between each integer and adjust as appropriate, but this changes the challenge a bit. (Maybe more than just a bit) Or, I guess the extra bits would just need to be added to the appropriate columns, easy peasy, right? :)

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy a tricky part with subtraction might be the strikethrough for borrowing.

Comment: @MichaelT It could, but I have an idea for how it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 48 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
¢≈3ä⌂♪s♂N#┼DuΦeÑα▼dσÿóYRC├[♂≡α%┴&UZ≤§╟Ω^j╪♪■∞xëa
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9bf733847f0d730b4e23c54475e865a5e01f64e598a2595243c35b0bf0e025c126555af315c7ea5e6ad80dfeec788961&i=%5B50,50%5D%0A%5B1651,+9879%5D%0A%5B6489789,+9874,+287%5D&m=2)

`)` is a lifesaver here, but it still feels too long.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```
L.[dJhl`eSQ`b:jk_.u/+NsYT.t_MjRTQ00\0djbyMPQXyeQ0\+*J\-ysQ
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L.[dJhl%60eSQ%60b%3Ajk_.u%2F%2BNssMYT.t_M%60MQ00%5C0djbyMPQXyeQ0%5C%2B*J%5C-ysQ&input=[6489789%2C+9874%2C+287]&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L.[dJhl%60eSQ%60b%3Ajk_.u%2F%2BNssMYT.t_M%60MQ00%5C0djbyMPQXyeQ0%5C%2B*J%5C-ysQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=50%2C+50%0A1651%2C+9879%0A6489789%2C+9874%2C+287&debug=0)

Way too long. Should golf more.

#### Explanation

```
L                  helper function y = lambda b:
        eSQ          largest number in input
      l`             length as string
     h               increment
    J                save to J
 .[d       `b        pad argument with spaces to that length

                             carry row:
                jRTQ           each input to base 10
              _M               reverse each result
            .t      0          transpose, padding with zeroes
    .u               0         cumulative reduce from 0:
         sY                      sum digits of column
       +N                        add previous carry
      /    T                     floor-divide by 10
   _                           reverse
 jk                            join by ""
:                     \0d      replace 0 by space

          number rows:
    PQ      all input numbers but last one
  yM        pad to correct length
jb          print on separate lines

           last number row:
  eQ         last input number
 y           pad to correct length
X   0\+      change first char to +

        separator row:
 J        width of input (saved in helper)
* \-      that many dashes

       result row:
 sQ      sum of inputs
y        pad to correct length
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 326 bytes

Byte count does not include explanation, of course.

```
@echo off
set t=%*                            Get the space separated parameters
set t=%t: =+%                       Change the spaces into + signs
set/at=%t%,l=p=1                    Add together, and initialise length and power
set c=                              Carry string
set d=-                             Dash string
:l                                  Loop though each power of 10
set/al+=1,p*=10,s=t/p               Divide the total by the power
for %%n in (%*)do set/as-=%%n/p     Subtract each parameter divided
set c=%s%%c%                        Anything left must have been carried
set d=-%d%                          Add a - to the line of dashes
if %p% leq %t% goto l               Keep going until we run out of powers
echo(%c:0= %                        Delete any zeros in the carry and output it
:i                                  Loop through each parameter
set n=%d:-= %%1                     Pad it with a whole bunch of spaces
call set n=%%n:~-%l%%%              Extract the rightmost characters
if "%2"=="" set n=+%n:~1%           Insert a + before the last parameter
echo %n%                            And output it
shift                               Move to the next parameter
if not "%1"=="" goto i              Until they are all consumed
echo %d%                            Output the line of dashes
echo  %t%                           Output the total (with an indent for the +)
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 199 bytes

```
a=>[[...t=` `+a.reduce((t,n)=>t+n)].map((_,i)=>a.reduce((c,n)=>c-n[i],90+t[i])%10||` `),a=a.map(n=>(` `.repeat(l=t.length)+n).slice(-l))).join``,...a,`-`.repeat(l),t].join`\n`.replace(/ (?=.*\n-)/,`+`)
```

Where the first `\n` represents a literal newline character, while the second one is a two-character regexp escape sequence. Explanation:

```
a=>[                            Accept an array of numbers
 [...                           Split the total into digits
  t=` `+a.reduce((t,n)=>t+n)    Calculate the total and add a space
 ].map((_,i)=>a.reduce((c,n)=>  For each column
  c-n[i],90+t[i])               Subtract the column from the total
  %10||` `),                    Deduce the carry that was needed
  a=a.map(n=>                   For each input value
   (` `.repeat(l=t.length)+n)   Pad to the length of the total
    .slice(-l))                 Remove excess padding
 ).join``,                      Join the carries together
 ...a,                          Append the padded input values
 `-`.repeat(l),                 Append the dividing line
 t].join`\n`                    Append the total and join together
  .replace(/ (?=.*\n-)/,`+`)    Insert the + on the line above the -
```

The carry calculation works by taking the total digit, prefixing `90`, subtracting all the input value digits in that column, and taking the result modulo 10. (The prefix is `90` rather than `9` so that the leading column generates a blank carry space.)