# How many carries do I need to add these two numbers?

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

### Task

Given two positive integers, output the number of carries needed to add them together in long addition in base 10.

### Examples

```
¹¹¹   <-- carries
 999
+  1
----
1000
```

Three carries are needed.

```
 ¹
 348
+ 91
----
 439
```

One carry is needed.

### Testcases

```
999,   1 -> 3
398,  91 -> 1
348,  51 -> 0
348,  52 -> 2
  5,  15 -> 1
999, 999 -> 3
505, 505 -> 2
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74127/48934).

Comment: Suggested test case: `190192, 90909` (has a break in the carries).

Comment: From [@Jenny_mathy 's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125834/60043): the number of carries is equal to the difference between (1) the sum of the digit sum of the two inputs and (2) the digit sum of the sum of the two inputs, divided by nine. This is because when there is a carry, you subtract 10 from and add 1 to the digit sum. For instance, `9+9` gives you `18`, but the digit sum is `9+9-10+1` because there is a carry.

Comment: [Related anarchy endless challenge](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Count+Carries)

Comment: Can we assume the numbers fit in our language's int type? In particular for Python 2, should we deal with `repr` appending an `L` for numbers above `2**63-1`?

Comment: @xnor yes, you can.

Answer (score 21):

## Mathematica, <s>46</s> 39 bytes

```
x=Tr@*IntegerDigits;(x@#+x@#2-x@+##)/9&
```

**input**

> [348,51]

*-7 bytes from JungHwan*

Comment: Dang, I really like this method. The difference between (1) the sum of the digit sum of the two inputs and (2) the digit sum of the sum of the two inputs, is nine times the number of carries because when there is a carry, you subtract 10 from the digit sum and add 1 to the digit sum.

Comment: Me too! thanks for the golfing tips

Comment: Testcases say [348,51] should return 0 but I'm getting 56/3 when I run this...?

Comment: Welp, looks like it's working now. Not sure what Mathematica was doing before...

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes

<s>Fixed</s> Stolen from [ovs' solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125829/39244)

```
f=(a,b,c=0)=>a|b|c&&c+f(a/10,b/10,a%10+b%10+c>=10)
```

#### Explanation

```
f=(a,b,c=0)=>                                      Function taking two numbers and optional carry
             a|b|c                                 If a number or the carry are nonzero
                  &&                               Then
                    c+f(a/10,b/10,a%10+b%10+c>=10) Return carry plus all other carries
```

#### Carry explanation

```
a%10+b%10+c     Sum of mod 10 of the numbers and c - remember these are not floordiv'ed
           >=10 Greater than or equals to 10 (we can't use greater than 9 here)
```

```js
f=(a,b,c=0)=>a|b|c&&c+f(a/10,b/10,a%10+b%10+c>=10)
console.log([[999,1],[398,91],[348,51],[348,52],[5,15],[999,999],[256,64],[190192,90909]].map(test=>`${(test[0]+'').padStart(6,' ')}, ${(test[1]+'').padStart(6,' ')} -> ${f(...test)}`).join('\n'));
```

Comment: `348 , 52` should be `2`

Comment: How does this work? Could you add an explanation?

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 65 bytes

```c
i,l;f(a,b){for(i=l=0;a+b;a/=10,b/=10)i+=a%10+b%10+l>9?l=1:0;a=i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxRCsIwEESvIoVClqyYqIWuYfUsSSSyEFsp/hXPHhMURJgZ3sdj4vYWYymC2SXlMcCa5kUJZzbO6@D8jq3B0BZEs@@t0aFNPtMlsz1VjcW9yt3LpGB9LDI9k@r66@Y/HSZFRGihwoFGpA8dRxx@tG80oB3gq9cC1Ps3)

Comment: You don't need to initialise global variables.

Comment: @user1502040 you need to, if they're used inside the function without being initialized.

Comment: Just getting my head around the initialization here: the variables *are* zero-initialized automatically, but only once, so because function submissions on PPCG have to work if the function's run more than once, they need to be manually zeroed for the benefit of the second and subsequent runs.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>13 12 11</s>  9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte by porting [Jenny_mathy's Mathematic answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125834/53748).
-2 more bytes by better golfing :p

```
;SN$DFS:9
```

**[See the test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9862E/FxS3YyvL/0T2H2x81rfn/Pzra0tJSxzBWJ9rY0kLHEswwsdAxhTOMgAxTHUNTIAVSCcQgAQNTHSAGsgwtDQwtjXQsDYAwNhYA)**.

#### How?

```
;SN$DFS:9 - Main link: list of numbers, [a,b]     e.g.   [348,53]
   $      - last two links as a monad
 S        -   sum                                            401
  N       -   negate                                        -401
;         - concatenate                             [348,53,-401] 
    D     - convert to decimal lists     [[3,4,8],[5,3],[-4,0,-1]]
     F    - flatten                           [3,4,8,5,3,-4,0,-1]
      S   - sum                                               18
       :9 - integer divide by nine                             2
```

---

My 12 byte solution...

```
:⁵+
DUSç\>9S
```

A monadic link taking a pair of integers and returning the number of carries as an integer.

<s>*There is probably a shorter way though!*</s> There was!

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/qUeNWbS6X0ODDy2PsLIP///8fbWhpYGhppGNpAISxAA)** or see the [test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/qUeNWbS6X0ODDy2PsLIP/H91zuP1R05r//6OjLS0tdQxjdaKNLS10LMEMEwsdUzjDCMgw1TE0BVIglUAMEjAw1QFiIMvQ0sDQ0kjH0gAIY2MB).

#### How

```
:⁵+ · Link 1: perform a carry: right-column's-digit-sum, a; left-colum's-digit-sum; b
 ⁵  · literal 10
:   · a integer-divided by 10 - the carry amount
  + · add to b

DUSç\>9S · Main link: list of summands        e.g. [348,52]
D        · convert to decimal lists                [[3,4,8],[5,2]]
 U       · upend (reverse each)                    [[8,4,3],[2,5]]
  S      · sum (add the digits up)                 [10,9,3]
    \    · cumulative reduce with:
   ç     ·   last link (1) as a dyad               [10,10,4]
      9  · literal 9
     >   · greater than?                           [ 1, 1,0]
       S · sum                                     2
```

Comment: The many uses of `D` and `S`...

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>53</s> 45 bytes

```
f=(a,b,d=1)=>a+b<d?0:(a%d+b%d>=d)+f(a,b,d*10)
```

Saved 1 byte by adding an extra do-nothing iteration for carries into 1's place. Saved 7 bytes by appropriating @xnor's carry check. I also had a more elegant 45-byte version but it suffers from floating-point inaccuracy; it would work great translated to a language with exact decimal arithmetic:

```
f=(a,b,c=a+b)=>c<1?0:a%1+b%1-c%1+f(a/10,b/10)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,m=1:m<1e99and(~a%m<b%m)+f(a,b,m*10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc3BCoMwDADQ@74iFzFx3bBuwiK6Hxk7VLRMWKu4Xoa4X@9ad1kC4YUkZHq7x2gL73XzVKbtFCjRCtPIytSyZ1a2w49KTN0mhvYat2kmc/J6nMH1LweDhRsyswBJAvDEFwH84zmw/GMRWYbFMmK7CSVaci65CG0eku7VDkJM82AdpssKhyssa3oMP41yGN8K0JhFEJH/Ag)

For each place value `m=1, 10, 100, ..., 10**99`, checks if there is a carry at that place value. The overflow check `a%m+b%m>=m` is shortened to `~a%m<b%m`.

A nicer [45-byte variant](https://tio.run/##Tc3BCsIwDAbgu0@Ry1hrq66bAzPYXkQ8pMziwHVj9iJjz15TvZhA@AIJ//wOj8lXMbr2SaPtCUjbhpQF8r2gzCibma41UjlBJ1Noy0NGNy0Q7q8Ag4erQEQNRmoQFV404I9nZv3HMrHmwzrh@8Mj2WBhsOS14Ja3Zgdc8zL4IPJ1g0MH65YfOXOkIFKsBif2CVLK@AE) where floats `a` and `b` shifted down instead

```python
f=lambda a,b:a+b and(a%1+b%1>=1)+f(a/10,b/10)
```

sadly runs into float precision issues.

Comment: Can't you use `a+b<m` as your terminating condition?

Comment: @Neil It needs to be `<=` which is longer.

Comment: ``1e99and`` is nasty.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,c=0:c+a+b and c+f(a/10,b/10,a%10+b%10+c>9)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc3BCsIwDAbgu0@Ri6y1VdvpwAy2FxEPaWdx4Loxe5GxZ6@tXkzg5wskZHqHx@jLGF3zpMF0BCSNtI2qrSBhgHwHVjhGR62kyUFbrYTJYVvk0Y0zhPsrQO/hyhBRguYS2AkvEvDHc2L1xzKzSotVxvcmRbZGpbFMo0rNb/UGUk1z7wMrlhX2LSxrcUg/Bwosv5Xg2C6Dcx4/)

Comment: As @JonathanAllan pointed out, if you used a call to your function, you must declare it as well. That being said, your answer is 55 bytes

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder fixed it

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
|DO‚€SOÆ9÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/xsX/UcOsR01rgv0Pt1ke3v7/v6GlgaGlEZelARACAA)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Fixed.

Comment: `|DO‚€SOÆ9÷` for 10 bytes.

Comment: @Emigna That's pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 10 bytes

```
₁₂λ
```

Explanation:

```
            ppend the two inputs into a list
             oin them together
             um the characters
   ₁₂         Push the first input, then the second
             Ad.
             um the characters
             ubtract
             Integer diision by
        λ     nine (variable)
```

[Try it!](http://178.62.56.56:80/neim?code=%F0%9D%94%B8%F0%9D%90%A3%F0%9D%90%AC%E2%82%81%E2%82%82%F0%9D%94%BB%F0%9D%90%AC%F0%9D%95%8A%CE%BB%F0%9D%95%8D&input=190192%0A90909)

Alternative solution, also 10 bytes:

```
DS9
```

Explanation:

```
             ppend the two inputs into a list
 D            Duplicate
              oin
              um
    S          Swap
              um
              um the characters
              ubtract
              integer diide by
        λ       nine (variable)
```

[Try it!](http://178.62.56.56:80/neim?code=%F0%9D%94%B8D%F0%9D%90%A3%F0%9D%90%ACS%F0%9D%90%AC%F0%9D%90%AC%F0%9D%95%8A%CE%BB%F0%9D%95%8D&input=190192%0A90909)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP>=7.1, 81 Bytes

```
for([,$x,$y]=$argv,$i=1;($x+$y)/$i|0;$i*=10)$d+=$c=$x/$i%10+$y/$i%10+$c>9;echo$d;
```

-2 Bytes removing `|0` In this case the loop runs until `$i` is `INF`

[Test Cases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d47c0f55e9fbbc6779bc835f88ed1061292d5dd4)

Comment: When does `$i` become `INF`?

Comment: @cat I am not sure why it  is important. I have not use this. `1.0E+309`is the first  `INF` value [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQybQ2tVTJtPP3cgJSWraGBZmpyRr6SSmZMnpL1//9f8/J1kxOTM1IB "PHP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 20 bytes

```
VR{.M}d<d&+v+d&+c-9/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/LKhaz7c2xSZFTbtMG0gk61rq////39DSwNDS6L@lARB@zcvXTU5MzkgFAA)

Uses the same method as everyone else.

Could've saved a byte or 2 had I had the foresight to allow `d` to use the greedy modifier, then I could've replaced `d<d` with `&d` ah well, next time.

### Explanation

```
VR{.M}d<d&+v+d&+c-9/  Implicit input from commandline args
VR                    Create stack2 and return to stack1
  {..}                Foreach loop, runs on each item in stack1
   .M                 Duplicate and move duplicate to stack2
      d<d             Split both items on stack into digits
         &+           Sum entire stack
           v+         Switch to stack2 and sum last 2 items on stack
             d&+      Split result into digits and sum all digits
                c     Collapse stack2 into stack1
                 -    Subtract last item from 2nd to last
                  9/  Divide by 9
                      Implicit output of last item on stack
```